# Cannot log in after update to 19.04

Tags: login, password

I have recently updated to 19.04. It seems to have gone OK, but I do get a screen asking me what I want to do after I turn on my pc. It gives me the option of 1. Ubuntu 2. Test Memory....etc...I cannot remember the exact list of choices. Anyway I just choose 1 - Ubuntu. I have 2 user accounts on the machine (I am the only person with access). The accounts are MP and MM. I rarely use MM and do all my work through MP. Both have admin privilege. After I rebooted today MP stopped taking the password. It takes the password and seems to log in but then loops back to the log in screen with both users. I can log in with the MM profile and I have tried changing the MP password and that worked....it took the password...and again looped back and so I can go no further than that log in screen. I tried setting autologin for MP using MM's admin privileged...but it will not automatically log in. I can access the data and information on MP through MM....but I want to be able to log back into MP....what can I do? Thanks for your suggestions and help.

Comment: I'd suggest you switch to a text terminal & login to check you have space in $HOME (your user directory).  GUI logins require the creation of work files that are created in $HOME and if they cannot be created (because of lack of space), the login procedure fails & you are logged out without any message and it appears as a login-loop.  Your other account (MM) uses a different $HOME directory so it may have space thus works.  (`df -hl` to show disk free space, human output & local drives only, but only your /home/mp/ or $HOME directory matters for gui work-files)

Comment: Well, it gets more curious. With 19.04 I decided to change away from Unity. So I chose non unity option (I presumed this was gnome). This worked for a while and then went into the famous loop I could not get out of. On a whim I just tried logging in under Unity again....and it just worked??!!

Answer (score 1):

Probably the Gnome installation is missing something. After you boot your machine, try to press Ctrl+Alt+F5 to log in in text mode. Try to log in with your admin user and enter the following command:

```
$ sudo apt install gnome-session gnome
```

If the installation goes OK, type

```
$ shutdown -r 0
```

to restart you machine. Then try to login to a Gnome session again. Please note, that in the GUI password prompt screen there may be a gear icon (⚙️). Click that icon and select **GNOME** before entering your password.

Comment: Nope, I am afraid that did not work.