# Login loop after upgrade from 18.10 to 19.04

Tags: gnome, upgrade, login

I've tried the suggestion described in [Cannot log in after update to 19.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1135700/cannot-log-in-after-update-to-19-04) to no avail.

`$ sudo apt install gnome-session gnome`

Still stuck in bootloop though. I double-checked space left in the home folder as well. Plenty available still with 29% Use as suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1135700/cannot-log-in-after-update-to-19-04#comment1882676_1135700).

@milso suggested on https://askubuntu.com/a/1135250/702968 look at /var/log/syslog and check if you see some Gnome crash stacktrace.

This is what `tail /var/log/syslog` produced after my most recent attempt to log in:

```
gnome-shell[2904]: The offending signal was destroy on Gjs_DateMenuButton 0x55c82a2e55c0.
org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2904]:(EE) failed to read Wayland events: Connection reset by peer
gnome-session[2868]: gnome-session-binary[2868]: WARNING: App 'org.gnome.Shell.desktop' exited with code 1
gnome-session-binary[2868]: Unrecoverable failure in required component org.gnome.Shell.desktop
gnome-session-binary[2868]: WARNING: App 'org.gnome.Shell.desktop' exited with code 1
at-spi-bus-launcher[1992]: XIO: fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server ":0"
at-spi-bus-launcher[1992]:      after 21 requests (21 known processed) with 0 events remaining.
gdm3: GdmDisplay: display lasted 1.185092 seconds
systemd[1]: session-9.scope: Succeeded.
kernel: [  880.696202] logitech=hidpp-device 0003:046D:101A.0006 multiplier = 8
```

I was able to adduser and log in. Not sure how to proceed from there in order to get primary user logged in.

Following [steps delineated here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-sudo-user-on-ubuntu-quickstart), I was able to give my new user sudo privileges using `usermod -aG sudo username`. I now just use the secondary account. Not too much of an inconvenience. But I will welcome and try any suggestions to fix primary account login loop issue.

Comment: Please refer to [Login loop after upgrading to 19.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1135110/login-loop-after-upgrading-to-19-04) and [Ubuntu regolith Login loop after 19.04 to 19.10 upgrade](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1196334/ubuntu-regolith-login-loop-after-19-04-to-19-10-upgrade). There are discussions and different solutions. For me, it worked after removing chrome-remote-desktop.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu gets stuck in a login loop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop)