# Ubuntu regolith Login loop after 19.04 to 19.10 upgrade

Tags: 19.04, 19.10

Just upgraded from 19.04 to 19.10 Ubuntu Regolith Version (i3 desktop).

and the login just loops back to login after i enter password.

Anything i can do par wipe system down?

Thank you

Comment: See if https://github.com/regolith-linux/regolith-desktop/wiki/HowTo:-Upgrade-to-Ubuntu-19.10-(Eoan-Ermine) helps.

Comment: OK so messed tht up. tried to boot into grub menu to get into terminal but pressing shift not working

Comment: Had to press esc on manufacture boot screen then when it says press any key press esc again. how do i et into terminal from grub menu?

Comment: Sorry, I don't use regolith myself. I just posted a link in the hope it may help you.

Comment: certainly has. trying to boot into terminal from ubuntu grub which im in now. not sure... still googling

Answer (score 1):

Ok so if you have read this post after you installed the 19.10 update, then dont wworry can still fix it using option 2 from this link:

https://github.com/regolith-linux/regolith-desktop/wiki/HowTo:-Upgrade-to-Ubuntu-19.10-(Eoan-Ermine)

Connect laptop via cable LAN.
first you will need to enter grub menu.

Press shift for old bios or press ECP for Ufei. then press ESC again when it says press any key.

once in go to the second option.
Then boot to recovery.
Then enable networking.
then boot terminal.
once your there follow option 2 instructions.

Every back to normal.

Thank you@Justice for Monica

Answer (score 0):

Try logging into tty terminal.
 `Ctrl+Alt+f2` on login screen .Login with your credentials.
If successfully logged in,
try `startx` command to launch gui , alternatively try solving issue through cli itself.

Answer (score 0):

As sunew answered here [Login loop after upgrading to 19.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1135110/login-loop-after-upgrading-to-19-04), the chrome-remote-desktop is the reason for me. Go to the console using Ctrl+Alt+F2, and remove it:

```
$ sudo apt remove chrome-remote-desktop
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue after upgrading `Regolith Linux v1.2` from `19.04` to `19.10`.

Once you're on the graphical login press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> to open a new terminal session session. Login with your username and password and you'll be able to execute the steps in https://github.com/regolith-linux/regolith-desktop/wiki/HowTo:-Upgrade-to-Ubuntu-19.10-(Eoan-Ermine)#option-1

Once you want to return to the graphical session press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>